# Compressing JavaScript random sentence generator code

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to make a generator that creates a semi-random sentence based on pulling variables from arrays of different words at a randomly determined index, and then removing that word from the array to make sure that there's no repeats.

It works, but not in a way that's easy to build off of. Every time I want to pull from an array that's already been pulled from in the same line, the script just stops.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  genContent();
};

function genContent() {
 var content = "";
 lists();
// --- what works ---
  content += r(person).concat(" ", r(verb), "ed ");
  content += r(person).concat(", so ");
  content += r(person).concat(" is ", r(verb), "ing ");
  content += r(person);
  
// --- what I want to condense it down to ---
//  content += r(person).concat(" ", r(verb), "ed ", r(person), ", so ", r(person), " is ", r(verb), "ing ", r(person));


  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = content.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + content.slice(1);
};

function r(array) {
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  value = array[random];
  array.splice(random, 1);
  return value;
};

function lists() {

 person = ["Grace", "Jared", "Suzy", "Tommy"];
  verb = [
   "answer", "ask", "block", "call", 
    "delay", "expect", "follow", "greet", 
    "help", "inform", "join", "kick", 
    "label", "mark", "need", "order", 
    "pick", "question", "request", "signal",
    "trick", "visit", "warn"];
};
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="output" output="" rows="8" style="width:50%; min-width:285px;" readonly="readonly">
    Click the button to generate a sentence.
  </textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Make content" id="button">
</div>
```

<sub>[(jsfiddle link because it's easier to edit)](https://jsfiddle.net/bbiiggffoott/hrn6r9d4/)</sub>

Any ideas on how to achieve something along the lines of the commented out code(line 15)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it just that concat is making this very messy?  You can do this:

```
content = r(person) + " " + r(verb) + "ed " + r(person) + ", so "
    + r(person) + " is " + r(verb) + "ing " + r(person);
```

You could also use an array join, which is kinda nice since you can insert any character you want in between the elements, and you could use push() to build the array.

```
content = [r(person), " ", r(verb), "ed ", r(person), "
    , so ", r(person), " is ", r(verb), "ing ", r(person)];

content = content.join("");
```

Comment: You could actually join on the space character and that would help you clean up and not even need some of the array entries that are just empty spaces too!

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    var person = ["Grace", "Jared", "Suzy", "Tommy"];
    var verb = ["answer", "ask", "block", "call", "delay", "expect", "follow", "greet", "help", "inform", "join", "kick", "label", "mark", "need", "order", "pick", "question", "request", "signal", "trick", "visit", "warn"];
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = [r(person), r(verb) + "ed", r(person) + ", so", r(person), "is", r(verb) + "ing", r(person) + "."].join(" ");
});

function r(list) {
    return list.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length), 1)[0];
};
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <button>Go</button>
  <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a template such as:

```
"[P] [V]ed [P], so [P] is [V]ing [P]"
```

and use the `.replace()` method with a custom callback function:

```js
var person = [
      "Grace", "Jared", "Suzy", "Tommy"
    ],
    verb = [
      "answer", "ask", "block", "call", 
      "delay", "expect", "follow", "greet", 
      "help", "inform", "join", "kick", 
      "label", "mark", "need", "order", 
      "pick", "question", "request", "signal",
      "trick", "visit", "warn"
    ];

var template = "[P] [V]ed [P], so [P] is [V]ing [P]";

var str = template.replace(/\[([PV])\]/g, function(m, p0) {
  var list = {'P': person, 'V': verb}[p0];
  return list.splice((Math.random() * list.length) | 0, 1);
});

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach/implementation of your code, just as an inpsiration.:

```
//takes an Array, shuffles it in place (no copy), and returns the shuffled Array
function shuffle(arr){
    for(var len = arr.length, i=len, j, tmp; i--; ){
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (len-1));
        if(j>=i) ++j;
        tmp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = tmp;
    }
    return arr;
}

//a utility to uppercase only the first-char of a string
function uppercaseFirstChar(str){
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

//stringpool, 
//the code never mutates this, so there's no need to ever reset it.
var strings = {//TODO: find a better name(space) than `strings`
    persons: [
        "Grace", "Jared", "Suzy", "Tommy"
    ],

    verbs: [
        "answer", "ask", "block", "call", 
        "delay", "expect", "follow", "greet", 
        "help", "inform", "join", "kick", 
        "label", "mark", "need", "order", 
        "pick", "question", "request", "signal",
        "trick", "visit", "warn"
    ]
}

//keep the tasks simple and clear. 
//this function builds and returns a random sentence. 
//no more, no less.
//it doesn't need to know what the result is used for
function randomSentence(){
    //don't mutate the string-pool, create a copy of the Arrays, and shuffle that
    var person = shuffle( strings.persons.slice() );
    var verb = shuffle( strings.verbs.slice() );

    //build the sentence, uppercase the first char, and return the result
    return uppercaseFirstChar(
        `${person[0]} ${verb[0]}ed ${person[1]}, so ${person[2]} is ${verb[1]}ing ${person[3]}`
    };


    //an example how you can reference the same person/verb multiple times in the same result
    //your r(array)-approach is not able to that; it's kind of destructive.
    //return `${person[0]} ${verb[0]}ed ${person[1]}; ${person[1]} has been ${verb[0]}ed by ${person[0]}`
};


document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = randomSentence();
};
```